# Testing Oracle OutsideIn ImageExport on Solaris with Xvfb

Tags: x11, solaris, xvfb, oracle-outside-in

Has anyone had success testing Oracle Outside in on solaris using Xvfb?  The error messages are a pecious few and I'm not sure what configuration is the problem.

Process

- Edit /usr/openwin/server/etc/OWconfig

`class="XDISPLAY" name="99"
coreKeyboard="IKBD"
corePointer="ps22b"
listOfScreens="stvga"; et...`

- Start Xvfb: Xvfb :99 -ac
- Start window manager: metacity --display :99 --sm-disable --replace
- Setup font path to all font directories
- run test
- get error: SCCERR_DISPLAYOPENFAILED   0x087  /* Failed to open display (XOpenDisplay failed)                  */

Comment: Did you set the DISPLAY environment variable to ":99" when running the test so XOpenDisplay knew which one to open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found I had to pass the DISPLAY down to surefire.  I thought it would pick it up from the upper level shell, but I was mistaken.  The new shell spawned by surefire processes the standard shell init scripts and lacks the variable on my build machine.

```
<plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
     <configuration>
        <environmentVariables>
          <GDFONTPATH>${localFontDir}</GDFONTPATH>              
          <DISPLAY>${env.DISPLAY}</DISPLAY>              
        </environmentVariables>
     </configuration>

  </plugin>`
```